# Sinatra - Making nested URL?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm making a simple static site with Sinatra for my portfolio.

I want several pages under `/profile` like `/profile/history` and `/profile/education`

By following the official documentation, I can achieve this by:

```
get "/profile/history" do
    ...
end

get "/profile/education" do
    ...
end
```

It become redundant. Is there **DRY** way to do this? Maybe adding a `class` or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `sinatra-contrib` and use [Sinatra::Namespace](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace.html) to achieve this.

Example:

```
require "sinatra/base"
require "sinatra/namespace"

namespace '/profile' do
  get '/history' { ... }
  get '/education' { ... }
end
```

Comment: PERFECT! What about calling the template? The template is inside `/profile` subdirectory and to call it I use `erb :'profile/history'`. Any way to avoid writing the  subdirectory? Thanks again

Comment: It doesn't seem like `Sinatra::Namespace` knows about template subdirectories. Have you tried `erb :history`?

Comment: I tried `erb :history` and it doesn't work. I must specify the subdirectory `erb :'profile/history'`. It's good enough then. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation:

```
prefix = "/profile"

get "#{prefix}/history" do
    ...
end

get "#{prefix}/education" do
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one is okay but the answer above with using `sinatra-contrib` is cleaner

Comment: @DarcCode, I agree. davogones's answer is much better.